# How to write data(binary mode) in to a file only using std::filebuf?

Tags: c++, filebuf

Please examine following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    char mybuffer[512];
    std::filebuf* optr = new std::filebuf();
    optr->pubsetbuf(mybuffer, 512);
    const char sentence[] = "Sample sentence";
    auto ptr = optr->open("bd.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc | std::ios::out);
    if (ptr) {
        float fx = 13;
        auto n = optr->sputn(sentence, sizeof(sentence) - 1);
        n += optr->sputn(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&fx), sizeof(fx));
        optr->pubsync();
    }
    optr->close();
    if(optr) { delete optr; }
    return 0;
}
```

After run this program **no data** has been written in to the file while`sputn` -> `n` is returning valid amount of writtne characters(verified through debugging).

Answer (score 0):

You code runs fine on my system, producing a `bd.bin` with 19 characters.

Are you sure this is exactly what you built and ran? Perhaps you're using a problematic compiler, or you're out of disk space or something.

Comment: I am using VS2017 latest compiler :(

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga: My point is, your code is valid. The problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Use the right tool for the job. `filebuf` is just the buffer that is streamed into. The actual thing that does the writing in the iostreams API is [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream):

```
std::filebuf file;
if (file.open(...)) {
    std::ostream os(&file);
    os << sentence;
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&fx), sizeof(fx));
}
```

It's also easier to remember to use `<<` and `write()` rather than deal with the maze of cryptically named functinos that is the `streambuf` API.

Comment: ... but this is also not the write tool for OP's job, as s/he would probably want to be able to say `something << fx` and get the exact same effect as your `os.write()`, i.e. get the octets copied from memory into the file as is.

Comment: @einpoklum Well, if you could write that if you want to... `os << as_bytes(fx);`